# How to Get only the device GPS location ios

Tags: ios, gps, core-location

Is there any way to get the only device gps location using the corelocation in ios.
Currently i am using the following code.

```
- (id)init{
if (!(self = [super init]))
    return nil;

//Setup the manager
manager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
if (!manager) {
    return nil;
}
manager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
manager.delegate = self;
if ([manager respondsToSelector:@selector(pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically)]) {
    manager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;
}
if ([manager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)])
{
    [manager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
}

[manager startUpdatingLocation];

return self;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean ? You only want the actual GPS coordinates without the Wifi and Cellular precision ?

Comment: yes i want only gps cordinate if device supported not wifi or cellular.

Comment: The CoreLocation will give you a position calculated from GPS, Wifi and cellular Network. You can't ask it to use only a specific location method to calculate the position. The position calculation method is totally dark to you, and you shouldn't care about it.

Comment: i have checked my plist there two strings i have already added there. My device giving me location when not internet connect is available. But i only want device location wether internet is connected or not.

Answer (score 0):

You should add this code to your file. It is executed when a new location is received:

```
// Delegate method from the CLLocationManagerDelegate protocol.
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
      didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    // If it's a relatively recent event, turn off updates to save power.
   CLLocation* location = [locations lastObject];
   NSDate* eventDate = location.timestamp;
   NSTimeInterval howRecent = [eventDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
   if (abs(howRecent) < 15.0) {
      // If the event is recent, do something with it.
      NSLog(@"latitude %+.6f, longitude %+.6f\n",
              location.coordinate.latitude,
              location.coordinate.longitude);
   }

}
```

src: [Getting the Users Location - Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html)